# replace function in javascript array

Tags: javascript

We know javascript array.push appends elements to the array. Is there an option to replace the elements in the array? The below function gets called twice and I have no control over event.mediaCollection.mediaIds. So mediaDTOs array gets populated with same number of mediaIds twice. I wish to prevent that from happening.I'm looking to add new mediaIds everytime this function is called instead of pushing mediaIds to the same array.

```
function calledTwice(){
    var mediaIds = event.mediaCollection.mediaIds; 
    var mediaDTOs = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < mediaIds.length; i++) {
            mediaDTOs.push({id:mediaIds[i]});
    }
}
```

Edit: Can't afford to create a temporary object to achieve this. Got to get the ids in the mediaDTOs array to be unique.

Comment: Does mediaDTO's NEED to be an array?

Comment: Sorry for not being really clear, but xpapad has almost got what I was looking for. mediaDTOs needs to be an array, I'm not really understanding what difference an object would make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
mediaDTOs.push({id:mediaIds[i]});
```

to

```
mediaDTOs[i] = {id:mediaIds[i]};
```

but since mediaDTOs is local, I am not sure what the problem is...

Answer (score 0):

Use an object instead:

```
var mediaDTOs = { };
for(var i = 0; i < mediaIds.length; i++) {
   mediaDTOs[ mediaIds[i] ] = true;
}
```

Then you can get the unique ids with something like:

```
var ids = [];
for(var id in obj){
    ids.push(id);
}
```

Make sure you really want to make mediaDTOs local though...

Comment: Seems like an interesting answer. I did not understand the "obj" part though. Should I use mediaDTO instead of the obj in the second for loop?